# not rewriting .asp files using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have .asp files re-writing themselves to .php files using htaccess and a rewrite rule on another site. it works fine but I am trying to do the same on my other site with one URL and it doesn't work. both have mod_rewrite enabled and on similar servers. (Apache v3.22.17 rev9999 / PHP v5.4.21)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+).(asp)$ $1.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

this is the full htaccess code.. can you see anything wrong with this?

Comment: What doesn't work for you?

Comment: *.htaccess* is Apache, use http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite in IIS. What exactly is not working? Are you trying to do a redirect? Your *ASP server* uses Apache as well?

Comment: if someone goes to link 'www.site.com/link.asp' I need it to redirect to 'www.site.com/link.php'. I have moved server and on apache server.

Comment: My server doesn't do .asp.

Comment: OK my mistake. was putting an .asp file into the directory when it should be of been a .php file. This code works!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really good with mod_rewrite however have you tried this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.+).(asp)$ $1.php [L]
```